# Update Subtotal in Cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

config.xml for adding event:-

```
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
               <Mymodule_Cart_Model_Observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Mymodule_Cart_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>modifyPrice</method>
               </Mymodule_Cart_Model_Observer>
           </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

Observer.php:-

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Cart_Model_Observer

{

public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)

{

// Get the quote item

$item = $obs->getQuoteItem();

            // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

            // Load the custom price
            $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);

            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

        }


        protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
        {
            $qty = $item->getQty();
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $finalprice = $product->getFinalPrice();

            $productOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);

            foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value) {

                $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId()); 


                $flag = 0;
                foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
                    $values = $o->getValues();
                    if ($o->getTitle() == 'Package Options') {
                        foreach ($values as $v) {
                            if ($value['option_value'] == $v->getOptionTypeId()) {

                                $pkg_price = round($v->getprice(), 2); 


                                $pkg_weight = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $v->getTitle()), 10);

                                if($pkg_weight != 0){
                                $flag = 1;
                                if($qty > $pkg_weight){

                                    if($qty % $pkg_weight == 0){

                                         $pkg_count = $qty / $pkg_weight;

                                    }else{

                                        $pkg_count = floor($qty / $pkg_weight) + 1;

                                    }

                                }else{

                                     $pkg_count = 1;
                                  }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isset($pkg_count) and $pkg_count != 1){ 

            $newPkgPrice = $pkg_count * $pkg_price;

            $newPkgPriceSplitted = $newPkgPrice / $qty;
            $newPkgPriceSplitted = $newPkgPriceSplitted;
            $finalprice = $finalprice - $pkg_price;
            $newFinalPrice = $finalprice + $newPkgPriceSplitted;
            }
            if($flag > 0){ return $newFinalPrice; }



        }

    }

?>
```

Here I could change amount in unit price.But i want to add amount to subtotal instead of unit price.

Comment: Please help it's urgent

Comment: why need to change subtotal? i mean purpose of changing the subtotal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution :)

1. Overrided the Model 'Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item' and Added the event 'sales_quote_save_after'

vendor/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <quote_item>vendor_Mymodule_Model_QuoteItem</quote_item>
        </rewrite>
</sales>
</models>

<events>
    <sales_quote_save_after>
        <observers>
           <vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>modifyPrice</method>
           </vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
    </sales_quote_save_after>

    <sales_quote_save_after>
        <observers>
           <vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>modifyPrice</method>
           </vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
    </sales_quote_save_after>


</events>
</global>
```

2. Overrided the class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item and the function calcRowTotal() in my custom module

Vendor/Mymodule/Quoteitem.php

```
  <?php class Vendor_Mymodule_Model_QuoteItem extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
{
protected $customRowTotalPrice = null;

public function setCustomRowTotalPrice($price)
{
    $this->customRowTotalPrice = $price;
}

public function calcRowTotal()
{
    if ($this->customRowTotalPrice !== null) {

        $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->customRowTotalPrice));
        $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->customRowTotalPrice));
        return $this;
    }

    $qty        = $this->getTotalQty();
    // Round unit price before multiplying to prevent losing 1 cent on subtotal
    $total      = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;
    $baseTotal  = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;

    $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($total));
    $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($baseTotal));
    return $this;




    }

}


?>
```

3. Added observer event 'sales_quote_save_after' in vendor/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Vendor_Mymodule_Model_Observer    
   {
   public  function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
   {
   $salesQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
   $items = $salesQuote->getAllItems();

   foreach($items as $item):

     $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

       $qty = $item->getQty();
       $product = $item->getProduct();
       $finalprice = $product->getFinalPrice();
       $productOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);
       foreach($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value)
           {
           $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
           $flag = 0;
           foreach($product->getOptions() as $o)
               {
               $values = $o->getValues();
               if ($o->getTitle() == 'Package Options')
                   {
                   foreach($values as $v)
                       {
                       if ($value['option_value'] == $v->getOptionTypeId())
                           {
                           $pkg_price = round($v->getprice() , 2);
                           $pkg_weight = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $v->getTitle()) , 10);
                           if ($pkg_weight != 0)
                               {
                               $flag = 1;
                               if ($qty > $pkg_weight)
                                   {
                                   if ($qty % $pkg_weight == 0)
                                       {
                                       $pkg_count = $qty / $pkg_weight;
                                       }
                                     else
                                       {
                                       $pkg_count = floor($qty / $pkg_weight) + 1;
                                       }
                                   }
                                 else
                                   {
                                   $pkg_count = 1;
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }


       $newPkgPrice = $pkg_count * $pkg_price;
       $PkgPriceWithQty = $pkg_price * $qty;
       $finalprice = $finalprice - $pkg_price;
       $item->setCustomPrice($finalprice);
       $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalprice);
       $newfinalprice = $finalprice * $qty;
       $newfinalpricewithpkgprice = $newfinalprice + $newPkgPrice;
       $item->setCustomRowTotalPrice($newfinalpricewithpkgprice);
       $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
       $item->save();
       $salesQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
       $salesQuote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
       $salesQuote->collectTotals();



   endforeach; 

    }
      }    ?>
   ```

**NOTE:** '**sales_quote_save_after**' is the right event to modify Row Total price in cart.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the code

```
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)

    {

       // Get the quote item

      $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();

        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        // Load the custom price
        $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

         //for updating the totals
         $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote(); 
         $quote->collectTotals()->save(); 

    }
```

Comment: But it works but I need to change the row total of the product in cart instead of changing unit price

Comment: please see the image above

Comment: please it's urgent

Comment: Anyone here to help me?